# Synchronizing updating of properties in a separate thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, locking

I have a class that inherits from `BackgroundService`. It runs a task for the lifetime of the application, and in that task I have a loop that does some calculations, some of which use settable properties, that may be set from another thread. For one iteration of the loop, I have to ensure none of these properties change, so all my calculations happen using the same values.

The way I have handled this initially is to have my require properties actually just stick an action in a queue, and then those actions are executed at the beginning of my loop. So, I end up with something like this:

```
private MyConfig Config { get; set; }
private readonly ConcurrentQueue<Action> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<Action>();

public void UpdateConfig(MyConfig config)
{
    queue.Enqueue(() => Config = config);
}

protected async override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            for (int i = queue.Count; i > 0; i--)
            {
                queue.TryDequeue(out Action element);
                element?.Invoke();
            }
        }
        //now do some stuff with the updated config and maybe other properties too
    });             
}
```

I feel like there may be a better way. Should I just lock on those properties? At this point I'm not really sure the best solution.

Comment: Regarding the `MyConfig` type, is it a class or a struct?

Comment: Currently a class, but theoretically could be changed to a struct. I suppose I'm looking for an answer with it as a class for my own edification.

Comment: I asked about the type of `MyConfig`, because `struct` types have the added danger of [tearing](http://joeduffyblog.com/2006/02/07/threadsafety-torn-reads-and-the-like/). Your code doesn't seem to be susceptible to this problem though (assuming that the queue of actions is dequeued in only one place). So it doesn't really matter if the `MyConfig` is `class` or `struct`. (Btw I deleted my previous erroneous comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is what I would consider the standard pattern: using a [`lock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) object to synchronize the access to a shared field.

```
private readonly object _locker = new object();
private MyConfig _config;

public void UpdateConfig(MyConfig config)
{
    lock (_locker) _config = config;
}

protected async override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            MyConfig localConfig; lock (_locker) localConfig = _config;
            // Do stuff with the localConfig. Don't use the shared _config field.
        }
    });             
}
```

This should be thread-safe, provided that the `MyConfig` type is immutable. It should work equally well with either `class` or `struct` `MyConfig`.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. If I make the object immutable, the object that was passed in can't be changed externally. And if a new object is created and passed to the UpdateConfig method (or changed by the class privately somewhere else), it won't matter because I am using the localConfig object which is still referencing the original object that was passed in.

Comment: @gfree yeap, exactly. By using this pattern you minimize the interaction between threads to the very short protected regions inside the lock. (by interaction I mean waiting to acquire the lock in case it is taken by another thread). The immutability is a useful concept for simplifying the development of multithreaded applications. Btw Microsoft has implemented a whole bunch of [immutable collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/march/net-framework-immutable-collections) for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions to this problem. Your solution is valid, but it could run into issues. For example:

```
protected async Task AnotherThread ()
{
    var config = new MyConfig ();
    config.Property1 = 50;
    config.Property2 = 75;
    UpdateConfig ( config );
   
    // This statement breaks your threading approach.
    config.Property1 = 47;
 }
```

To prevent that work with a copy. Take a look at the config class below. This class will allow us to create a copy in a thread safe manner.

```
public class MyConfig
{
    private readonly object _sync = new object();

    public Int32 _property1;
    public Int32 Property1
    {
        get
        {
            lock ( _sync )
            {
                return _property1;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            lock ( _sync )
            {
                _property1 = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public Int32 _property2;
    public Int32 Property2
    {
        get
        {
            lock ( _sync )
            {
                return _property2;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            lock ( _sync )
            {
                _property2 = value;
            }
        }
    }

    // this method will create a copy of the current configuration. 
    public MyConfig Copy ()
    {
        MyConfig copy = new MyConfig();

        // locking here will prevent changes to the properties of this instance
        lock ( _sync )
        {
            // copy all properties while changes from other threads are prevented.
            copy.Property1 = Property1;
            copy.Property2 = Property2;
        }
        // changes are allowed to properties of this instance again.
        return copy;
    }
}
```

Then,

```
protected async override Task ExecuteAsync ( CancellationToken stoppingToken )
{
    await Task.Run ( async () =>
    {
        while ( !stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested )
        {       
            MyConfig copy = Config.Copy ();

            // nothing outside of this thread has a reference to this copy of the configuration...
            // so unless you do something silly in your Calculations it will be safe to use.
            // In addition, since the properties of MyConfig are thread-safe, 
            // Config can be edited from other threads.
            Calculations ( copy );
        }
            
    } );
}
```

Finally, thanks to our changes to the config class our update method doesn't really need to worry about thread safety.

```
public void UpdateConfig ( MyConfig config )
{
    // update reference to new object
    Config = config;
}
```

EDIT: In response to comment.

Another option would be an immutable Config class. I won't go into implementation details, but this allows you to share the reference freely without worrying about the object mutating.

Finally, there are many different libraries that could be used to prevent code bloat and mistakes in the first solution. It would probably be worth checking out AutoMapper.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the first scenario; I didn't consider that issue due to the creator of the config still having a reference to the object. I knew a copy was a valid solution here, but I didn't know if it was the best solution in the scenario where you might have lots of properties or nested objects. Seems that may become quite combersome if needing to make a deep copy.

Comment: It can be quite cumbersome as far as coding goes, but performance wise is really not that big a deal. As far as the best solution, without more detail it would be hard to recommend a "best" solution. A piece of advice that has served me well is, "Don't let perfect be the enemy of the good." I will update my post with a few other options, but in my opinion they leave quite a bit to be desired.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be inclined to change your code to this:

```
private MyConfig Config { get; set; }
private readonly ConcurrentQueue<Action<MyConfig>> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<Action<MyConfig>>();

public void UpdateConfig(Action<MyConfig> configAction)
{
    queue.Enqueue(configAction);
}
protected async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            for (int i = queue.Count; i > 0; i--)
            {
                queue.TryDequeue(out Action<MyConfig> element);
                element?.Invoke(this.Config);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This ensures that the only way to update the config is through this method. You're only ever working on the `private MyConfig Config { get; set; }` variable in your class.

I would also worry about concurrent calls to `ExecuteAsync` so I would suggest ensuring that you're only running one lot of dequeueing at a time.